# Not able to access interface methods from an abstract class instance

Tags: apex, interface, oop, abstract

I'm trying to build an Apex classes structure where I have two (or more) entities that have something in common but at the same time have a different set of fields. In the example below it's gonna be some Google/Microsoft context of something.

Let's say I have an interface with the method that returns an instance of another interface:

```
global interface IContext {
    IUserDetails getUser();
}

global interface IUserDetails {
    Integer getId();    
    String getUsername();
}
```

Apart from that I also have an abstract class that implements the interface above:

```
global abstract class Context implements IContext {
    /// Some common fields or logic here...
}
```

The trick I'm using here is that I'm not implementing the interface. It's allowed since this is an abstract class. I want the children's classes to implement these methods:

```
global class GoogleContext {
    global GoogleUserDetails getUser() {
        return new GoogleUserDetails();
    }

    global class GoogleUserDetails implements IUserDetails {
        global Integer getId() {
            return 1;
        }

        global String getUsername() {
            return 'google.username';
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `getUser()` method return type is different from the interface method type. This is also allowed because `GoogleUserDetails` implements `IUserDetails`. I made it like that so that it would be convenient to operate instances of this context like this:

- if I explicitly refer to `GoogleContext` then I would get access to all properties for `GoogleUserDetails` class;
- if I do not explicitly cast the context then I can just use all interface methods from `IUserDetails`.

Now, the actual problem I'm facing is that I'm not able to access the interface methods from the `Context` instance, though `Context` implements `IContext`:

```
// Let's assume this factory returns some instance of a context
Context ctx = new ContextFactory().createContext();

IUserDetails userDetails = ctx.getUserDetails(); // <-- I get the compilation error here
```

For some reason, the `getUserDetails()` method is not visible from the `Context` instance. However, it DOES implement the interface with that method. To solve this I have to always cast `Context` to `IContext`.

This doesn't make any sense to me. I would love to know what's wrong with this structure and why I get that compilation error. Right now I'm assuming this is not supposed to work like that.

My apologies for the long description.

UPD:

To make the example a bit simpler, describing the problem:

```
public interface IFoo {
    String getStr();
}

public abstract class Foo implements IFoo {
}

public class FooA extends Foo {
    public String getStr() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, if I create an instance of the abstract class and try to access its interface methods, I get a compilation error:

```
Foo f = new FooA();
System.debug(f.getStr());   // <-- Compilation error: "Method does not exist or incorrect signature"
```

Comment: Apex is not Java and does not support covariant return types. It is also not a perfectly implemented language compiler, so can have strange behaviours when you do something it doesn't really support. You hit one of those cases. Do not use covariance and things should work correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariant Return Types in Interfaces](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375502/covariant-return-types-in-interfaces)

Comment: I mean... The only answer I get from that question is "You should not use Apex like that at all". I understood the concern about using covariant return types. But in my question, I believe, the real problem is that the abstract class, extending an interface, does not see the interface methods. I thought it would make sense to paint the full picture of what I'm trying to do. That's why covariant return types for interfaces are mentioned here. I guess I'll update the question, with a simpler example. Thanks for your feedback though

Comment: Updated the question. Although, I have a suspicion that there's no real answer to that and the conclusion would be to just not use Apex like that...

Comment: You should not be able to instantiate an abstract class directly at all. Make it virtual if you want to be able to specialise it but also instantiate it.

Comment: I am able to create an instance of an abstract class by using a child class constructor, just like it's shown in the question.

Comment: So you are not creating an instance of the abstract class, but rather a concrete extension of the abstract class. That makes more sense. Since you are extending to add the interface method you likely need to use the keyword `override` when defining the `FooA.getStr` method since you are, at that point, overriding the required method. Your implementation is probably wrong because of this missing keyword, and I believe this leads to this confusing scenario. I don't believe there is a formal language specification, and the implementation has plenty bumps, like this.

Comment: "A concrete extension of the abstract class" is still an instance of the abstract class, the same way that I can say "an instance of an interface". If you look at the example, the `getStr` method is not an abstract or virtual method, this is a method of the `IFoo` interface, which means I don't need to override anything, I'm implementing that method.

Comment: Try adding `override` and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: No, it does not resolve the problem. I can't save the class with override keyword for that method, getting two errors: 1) override specified for non-override method; 2) class must implement IFoo.getStr() method.

Comment: So you will have to provide abstract implementations of the interface methods in `Foo` then override them in `FooA`. We have done workarounds like this in the past.

Comment: I have recently faced a similar problem, and I didn't want to re-define `abstract`/`virtual` method on the parent class (to avoid using the `override` in ancestor classes).

So I was able to solve that by explicitly casting the instance to the interface type, like: `System.debug(((IFoo) f).getStr());`.

Or, in internal methods usage: `((IFoo) this).getStr();`

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution I decided to use in the end. Looks ugly but at least it work.